# How do you nudge in Xcode interface builder?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I have a view that I want to nudge a few pixels, but I can't seem to select it in any way that allows nudging. The easiest way for me to select it is by clicking its name in the object list on the left:

[image]

But using the arrow keys just moves the selection in that list up and down, selecting different things.

If I actually click the view in the preview window, it ends up selecting something behind it (there is a full-size background image that get selected no matter what I click on).

If I select the name in the object list and hit Tab (thinking to change focus to the layout pane) it just enters a name-edit mode (?!). Hitting Tab multiple times never seems to give focus to the layout pane:

[image]

Seriously, this UI is defective. How do I select an object to nudge it with the arrow keys? Is there a way?

Comment: Double-click an item in the list to activate it.  You can also use the navigation bar at the top of the window.

Comment: Ah! That works too, and is much quicker than my method. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well I figured it out... one way at least, just by experimenting with every possible modifier combination. :) Turns out if you hold Shift and Right-Click in the layout view (or Ctrl-Shift-Click) you get a menu of all objects under the cursor:

[image]

And thankfully picking one of these keeps the layout pane focused so you *can* actually nudge objects around. Still not particularly intuitive but it works!

Comment: No prob, I actually use it all the time now myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep clicking the object until IB selects it.

If you have this hierarchy of views:

```
View 1
  View 2
    View 3
```

and click View 3 in the editor (not in the list on the left) IB will select the highest ancestor (View 1). View 1 will also be highlighted in the editor. When you click View 3 again,  the next view down the hierarchy will be selected (View 2). On the third click on View 3, View 3 will be selected.

This might seem unintuitive, but it actually makes sense. You want to be able to select the parent view even if it is completely covered by its subviews. So IB first selects the parent.

Comment: This is not the behavior I see. Xcode always selects the child-most node on first click, and subsequent clicks change the selection *mode* to something I don't understand, but while the first mode allows nudging, it doesn't select the object I want in the first place.

Comment: I just tested it. You're right, it seems to depend on what type of view you're clicking. Somewhat unpredictable. I didn't know about the ctrl-shift-click thing, nice discovery!